# Model Binding in Asp.Net Core from an Ajax call

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-core, model-binding

I have a Javascript function that makes a call to a Asp.Net Core controller:

```
    const details =
    {
        thisModel: {
            Id: '@Model.OrderId',
            Name: '@Model.Name',
            Data: data,
            StringData: ''
        }
    };

    const data = JSON.stringify(details);

    $.ajax({                    
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Orders/CreateOrder",
        data: data,
        datatype: "json",
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function (data) {
            // Success!
        }
    });
```

I'm trying to call an Asp.Net Core controller method:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> CreateOrder([FromBody]OrderDetails orderDetails)
    {
```

The OrderDetails model looks like this:

```
public class OrderDetails
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IFormFile Data { get; set; }
    public string StringData { get; set; }
}
```

The problem that I have is that, whilst the controller method does get called, every value inside orderDetails is null. I've looked [at the MS documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-3.1) and, as far as I can tell, I'm following all the rules, so I'm a little unsure why the data isn't being passed through. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have an `IFormFile` property in your model I understand that you want to upload a file to your API.

The problem here is that you can't upload a file inside a JSON. It is a "*limitation*" of HTTP protocol. To upload a file you should use [`FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects)

Given that you already have an html form like this:

```html
<form method="post" name="fileinfo">
  <label>Your file:</label>
  <input type="file" name="data" required />
  <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
```

Then you should add new hidden fields to store the `@Model.OrderId` and `@Model.Name`:

```html
<form method="post" id="fileUploadForm">
  <input type="hidden" name="OrderId" value="@Model.OrderId" />
  <input type="hidden" name="Name" value="@Model.Name" />
  <label>Your file:</label>
  <input type="file" name="Data" required />
  <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
```

Now on your javascript code you need to convert your forms inputs into an new `FormData` variable and then submit it to your api. The easiest way to do this is:

```
var form = $('#fileUploadForm')[0];

var data = new FormData(form);

$.ajax({                    
    type: "POST",
    url: "/Orders/CreateOrder",
    data: data,
    enctype: 'multipart/form-data', // Important!!!!
    processData: false,  //prevent jQuery transforming the data into a query string
    contentType: false,
    cache: false,
    success: function (data) {
        // Success!
    }
});
```

Comment: This does solve my problem, so thankyou for that.  However, I was getting the same behaviour even where the file was null

Comment: I'll do some tests to understand why the same behavior occours even when the file is null. I don't know for sure why it happens, but I believe that is because you have an IFormFile in your model and Asp.net model binding MAYBE validates it first and do not bind anything. Or because what I told in the deleted answer. Anyway I'm glad to help and will look deeper in Asp.Net Model Bind to understand this.